# Sequelize $not with $any

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

Can this query be converted with sequelize operators?

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE NOT ('manager' = ANY(roles))
```

Seems like this kind of query is impossible as everything involving `$not` and `$any` operator starts throwing errors for me

Comment: Should be possible.  You might get an answer if you provided a) what you've tried and b) what specific error messages you've received.

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late, but maybe will help someone.

You have two option either total Sequelize or add little Sql raw where query.

**Total Sequelize**

```
Db.users.findAll({
    where: {
        "manager": {
            $notIn: [roles]
        }
    }
 });
```

**Raw Query**

```
Db.users.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.literal(`(manager NOT IN (${roles}) )`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to select **1 user** from table **users**. Sequelize support function [**findOne**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOne)

```
users.findOne({ where: {
        "manager": {
            $notIn: [roles]
        }
    }
})
.then(user => {
})
.catch(err =>{
});
```